# IBM Watson Assistant - check for @sys-date with condition

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-assistant

In another Q&A you suggested me and I built the following conditions to check for legal age based on the birthday:

```
@sys-date.plusYears(18)<= today()

@sys-date.minusYears(18)<= today()
```

How can I add an additional condition that warns the user that he has not entered a correct date in the input and characters for having used only or even letters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a dialog node in IBM Watson Assistant with [conditional responses](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-overview#dialog-overview-multiple) and already have two conditions (old enough / too young), then you could add have a third response without any condition.

Conditions are checked in the order top down. If there is an unconditional answer, it serves like an ELSE. There you could  respond with some help about the format.